# Best way to render only the visible cluster items on a google map

Tags: android, google-maps, render, markerclusterer

I have a map fragment that is handled by google's cluster manager that I configured with my custom cluster renderer `extends DefaultClusterRenderer`.

I have overritten the functions `onBeforeClusterItemRendered` and `onBeforeClusterRendered` to be able to diplay my pictures:

[image]

Now If the user zooms in it makes no sense to render the items that are not in the visible area.
It's very easy to find out if the item is in the visible area:

```
private Boolean isInBounds(LatLng position) {
    return map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.contains(position);
}
```

But if I skip the rendering if the item is not currently visible, it will be empty when the user scrolls on the map.

So who knows how to get an event if the user scrolls and how to re render the items that are not in the visible bounds? (switchen from visible to non visible and vice versa)?

(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: How did you load the images on the clustered markers? Any sample code. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution. It works very well and renders only the visible items.
I use the camera changed listener to re render the items that became visible now:

```
private void onBeforeClusterOrClusterItemRendered(final Cluster<MediaItem> cluster, final MediaItem mediaItem, final MarkerOptions markerOption
    if(!isAdded())
        return;

    // In visible area?
    Marker marker = cluster == null ? getMarker(mediaItem) : getMarker(cluster);
    Boolean isInBounds = isInBounds(marker != null ? marker.getPosition() : mediaItem.getPosition(), null);

    if(isInBounds) {
        // ...
    }
}

private Boolean isInBounds(LatLng position, LatLngBounds latLngBounds) {
    return (latLngBounds == null ? mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds : latLngBounds).contains(position);
}

@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(final MediaItem mediaItem, final MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    onBeforeClusterOrClusterItemRendered(null, mediaItem, markerOptions);
}

@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(final Cluster<MediaItem> cluster, final MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    final MediaItem mediaItem = MediaPicker.getBestRated(new ArrayList<>(cluster.getItems()));
    onBeforeClusterOrClusterItemRendered(cluster, mediaItem, markerOptions);
}
```

...

```
// Re render
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        mClusterManager.onCameraChange(cameraPosition);
        final LatLngBounds latLngBounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

        // Cluster only
        Collection<Marker> clusters = mClusterManager.getClusterMarkerCollection().getMarkers();
        for(Marker marker : clusters) {
            if(isInBounds(marker.getPosition(), latLngBounds))
                onBeforeClusterRendered(getCluster(marker), new MarkerOptions());
        }

        // Cluster item only
        Collection<Marker> markers = mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers();
        for(Marker marker : markers) {
            if(isInBounds(marker.getPosition(), latLngBounds))
                onBeforeClusterItemRendered(getClusterItem(marker), new MarkerOptions());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: isAdded() method is missing

Comment: You can skip this line if needed. It's a method of Fragment.

Comment: I changed my code after a few tests to ADD only visible items on the map. This makes it much smoother.

Comment: calling  mClusterManager.onCameraChange(cameraPosition); gives me a stackoverflow exception.

Comment: hi, can someone clarify what exactly to put inside `if(isInBounds) {
        // ...
    }`

Comment: what is MediaPicker.getBestRated(new ArrayList<>(cluster.getItems())); in this solution?

Comment: @Kintanpatel Nothing interesting for you ;). Please simply use cluster.getItems().get(0)

See my app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levionsoftware.photos too see how good it can work.

Comment: @DennyWeinberg  I checked out your app and it works very well and smooth!!! Does the first section go in a custom renderer class? does the second section go in the onMapReady? I would love some help implementing your solution.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue. I track initial location of the user and show map markers around him. If user chooses to look outside initial zoom, I download additional markers. Implementation:

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                setCurrentRadius();
                viewCenter = cameraPosition.target;
                if (isNewGrounds(viewCenter, viewRadius)) {
                    downloadExtraPrinters(viewCenter,viewRadius);
                }
                myClusterManager.onCameraChange(cameraPosition);
            }
        });

   private void setCurrentRadius() {
        Projection projection = map.getProjection();
        VisibleRegion currentView = projection.getVisibleRegion();
        LatLng cameraCenter = map.getCameraPosition().target;
        float[] projectionRadius = new float[1];
        Location.distanceBetween(currentView.farLeft.latitude, currentView.farLeft.longitude, cameraCenter.latitude, cameraCenter.longitude, projectionRadius);
        viewRadius = Math.round((projectionRadius[0] / 1000.0f) + 0.5f);
    }

 /** Method checks if camera goes outside bounds of previously downloaded area **/
    protected boolean isNewGrounds(LatLng center, int radius) {
        //Check if it is the first time to update
        if (coveredGroundsCenter== null) {

            coveredGroundsCenter=center;
            coveredGroundsRadius= (int)(radius * EXTRA_RADIUS);

            return true;
        }else {
            float[] centerDistance = new float[1];
            Location.distanceBetween(coveredGroundsCenter.latitude, coveredGroundsCenter.longitude, center.latitude, center.longitude, centerDistance);

            int criticalDistance = (int) Math.round((centerDistance[0] / 1000.0f) + 0.5f) + radius;

            if (coveredGroundsRadius >= criticalDistance) {
                return false;
            } else {
                coveredGroundsCenter = center;
                coveredGroundsRadius = (int) (radius * EXTRA_RADIUS);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

EXTRA_RADIUS is a constant I use to have a small margin outside visible map area, so the smallest camera movement wouldnt cause my map to download and re-render. I choosed this margin to be 50 percent of the current radius:

```
 private static final double EXTRA_RADIUS=1.5;
 private LatLng coveredGroundsCenter;
 private int coveredGroundsRadius;
 private LatLng viewCenter;
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that I can use a part of your code.

Comment: Your answer is useful but in the cameraUpdateListener I can't force to rerender the items that are in the non visible area.

If I call clusterManager.clear and clusterManager.add... it works (force rerender all items), but this is not clean and all items are flashing...

Comment: Hm. thats how I implemented it. I clear and then add them. Im also using custom markers (~400 on screen )same way you do. No flashing, no blinking.  idk, maybe markers picture quality is set too high? 
If you find some optimization please let me know, maybe I could improve my code too :)

Comment: Yeah I think that I have a good solution. I will try it out and let you know if I have something interesting ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late, but I hope I can help someone. I tried to find a solution, but I didn't succeed, so I started looking for a solution through clustering classes. I found a class called NonHierarchicalViewBasedAlgorithm but it didn't work properly or I used it incorrectly. And based on this class, I wrote my own using LatLngBounds. It's called VisibleBoundsAlgorithm.

**Note**: You must call the updateBounds() method before each clustering. Use this in onCameraIdleListener

Here is code:

VisibleBoundsAlgorithm.java

```
package com.example.demo.app;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterItem;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.algo.NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.algo.ScreenBasedAlgorithm;
import com.google.maps.android.geometry.Bounds;
import com.google.maps.android.quadtree.PointQuadTree;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class VisibleBoundsAlgorithm<T extends ClusterItem>
    extends NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm<T> implements ScreenBasedAlgorithm<T> {
private final GoogleMap map;
private LatLngBounds bounds;

public VisibleBoundsAlgorithm(GoogleMap map) {
    this.map = map;
    bounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
}

@Override
protected Collection<QuadItem<T>> getClusteringItems(PointQuadTree<QuadItem<T>> quadTree, float mapZoom) {
    long oldMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Getting time before operations

    //Getting all items from QuadTree
    List<QuadItem<T>> items = new ArrayList<>(quadTree.search(new Bounds(0, 1, 0, 1)));

    ListIterator<QuadItem<T>> itemIterator = items.listIterator();

    while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {
        QuadItem<T> item = itemIterator.next();
        if (!bounds.contains(item.getPosition())) { //if map do not contain item on this position remove it
            itemIterator.remove();
        }
    }

    long newMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.println(Log.ERROR, "Clustering items", "end in: " + (newMillis - oldMillis) + " (" + TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(newMillis - oldMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) + " seconds)");
    return items; //Returning new massive of items
}

/**
 * Call this before clustering.
 */
public void updateBounds() {
    bounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
}


//When map is moving or zooming it should re-cluster
@Override
public boolean shouldReclusterOnMapMovement() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
    //required
}
```

}

In your Activity class:

```
ClusterManager<MyItem> cluster = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(context, map);

VisibleBoundsAlgorithm<MyItem> visibleBoundsAlgorithm = new VisibleBoundsAlgorithm<MyItem>(map);

cluster.setAlgorithm(visibleBoundsAlgorithm);
cluster.addItems(items);
cluster.cluster();

map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        visibleBoundsAlgorithm.updateBounds();
        cluster.cluster();
    }
});
```

If someone have a question ask me.